# Unable to access one of the table in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a production database which has 200 tables. Since last week I am unable to access one of the tables. When I just select top 100 rows it keeps on running.

How can I find out why the table is not accessible? How can I find if there is any lock on the table? All the other tables are running fine

Comment: Please provide some details about the table that is giving you the problem. What is the structure, size, and do you have any indexes? What is the query you are trying to execute on it, and what does your data look like?

Comment: any open transaction?

Comment: Do not assume there's something wrong with the table when it's a query that fails. You have a query that takes so long that you never get any answers even when you use a TOP 100 clause. What is the query, how many rows are in the table, do you have the proper indexes? Is the table locked? Do you get any results if you do a simple SELECT? A SELECT with the `WITH (NOLOCK)` table hint? If NOLOCK works it means all records are locked by another transaction that hasn't committed yet.

Comment: I have selected Top 100 rows with no lock,Still having the same problem.I have same table in the development environment which is running fine.The table has around 500K records

Answer (score 6):

From what I understood, you are not able to get any results when you query it.

There may be a lot of reasons for that.

1) **It could be locked**. 
    To do a *dirty read*, try querying with `NOLOCK` hint.

```
SELECT Column1 FROM TableName WITH (NOLOCK)
```

To check if there are locks on the table, use the script below:

```
declare @a table (
spid int,
[dbid] int,
objid int,
indid int,
[type] varchar(10),
resource varchar(100),
mode varchar(2),
[status] varchar(20)
);

insert into @a
exec sp_lock

select object_name(objid) tablename, * from @a where object_name(objid) = 'TableName'
```

2) Queries might be slow when **statistics are outdated**. Try updating them.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.TableName;
```

3) **The `TOP` operator itself**. The top operator basically takes the entire set of data and sorts it and gives you the first 100. You can add query hints to get some data *before* it is sorted.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Column1 FROM TableName (OPTION FAST(1))
--Have avoided doing a `SELECT * FROM....`

SELECT 1 FROM TableName (OPTION FAST(1))
--Without `TOP`
```

Comment: If there're locks on the table, how do we investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

Check Permissions on the table.  Right click on the table and select properties.  Click on the permissions tab and make sure you have access to that table.

Comment: I have admin access to the database.When i tried to access the table properties its giving me error 'Cannot show requested dialog,Lock request time out period exceeded(Error : 1222)'

Comment: If possible restart the SQL Service on the box.